# Map File Editor

Tags: android, android-studio, maps, mapsforge

I'm Creating an Offline Map for Android.But i only need a certain part of the Map.At the moment I can View my whole country using Mapsforge.

The map is provided by Mapsforge .What I want is to get some continent of my country. I don't want to use MOBAC as the files are too large.